# Excel VBA copying data - Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy some data from rows 106:110 into another sheet but am getting the following error - Object doesn't support this property or method - on this line:

```
sourceRange.Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.CopyAfter Destination:=destinationRange
```

Here is the full code

```
Sub CopyData()

    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Set sourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A106:A110")

    ' Get the destination sheet
    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
    Set destinationSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If destinationSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet DCF_Consolidated not found. Skipping data copying."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Copy the data to the destination sheet
    Dim startingRow As Long
    startingRow = 5

    ' Loop through the rows in the source range
    Dim currentRow As Integer
    For currentRow = 1 To sourceRange.Rows.Count

        ' Define the destination range for the current row
        Dim destinationRow As Long
        destinationRow = startingRow + currentRow - 1

        Dim destinationRange As Range
        Set destinationRange = destinationSheet.Rows(destinationRow)

        ' Copy the current row to the destination range
        sourceRange.Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.CopyAfter Destination:=destinationRange

    Next currentRow

End Sub
```

Comment: There isn't a method `CopyAfter`.

Comment: @taller, thank you. What can I use to achieve this?

Comment: _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Range.Copy method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144104)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Please, try the next way: `sourceRange.Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=destinationRange.Cells(1).offset(1)`. It should copy the respective row just bellow `destinationRange`.

Comment: Thank you @FaneDuru, do you know how I can amend it to paste as values?

Comment: Try `destinationRange.offset(1).value = sourceRange.Rows(currentRow).EntireRow.value`. But it would be better if you do not copy (even as values) **all the row**. You should copy only the columns having values (Intersect the row with UsedRange to obtain the shorter more efficient range)... Then resize the destination in terms of source number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next adapted code, not needing any iteration, which should be very fast:

```
Sub CopyData()
    Dim sourceRange As Range, arr
    Set sourceRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A106:A110")

    ' Get the destination sheet
    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
     Set destinationSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If destinationSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet DCF_Consolidated not found. Skipping data copying."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Copy the data to the destination sheet
    Dim startingRow As Long: startingRow = 5 'here you can calculate the first empty row, for future similar processing, if needed...
    
    'drop the source array content in the destination sheet:
    With destinationSheet.Range("A" & startingRow).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2))
        .value = arr
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.